# Why do I get errno 5 when I try to write a packet to a TAP device on linux?

Tags: linux, network-programming

When I try to write a `BOOTP` request packet to a `tun` device file descriptor with `write(2)`, I get `errno 5`. Any ideas why? I've already checked that the `IP`-level and `UDP`-level checksums are correct. The program is able to write `ARP` reply packets using `write(2)`. I've tried running it as root, the same problem occurs.

```
test: output packet: ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.0a.f7.1f.f8.08.02.08.00.45.00.01.48.00.00.00.00.40.11.79.a6.00.00.00.00.ff.ff.ff.ff.00.44.00.43.01.34.05.88.01.01.06.00.be.ba.fe.ca.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0a.f7.1f.f8.08.02.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
write: errno=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. To send an `IP` packet, the `tap` interface must be configured with an `IP` address.